# What to do if gate agents refuse to accept my ID?

Tags: air-travel, passport-stamps

I'm a dual national of a North African country and a European country, and for specific reasons I hold a passport of that North African country and ONLY the ID of that European country.

In a future travel I may do, after traveling from Europe to this particular country, I vacation there. For the flight back to Europe, at check-in, I want to only show the European ID because Europe allows entry to all of its citizens with an ID (I will have entered the African country with my North African passport and got it stamped, likewise for exit - this is about checkin not immigration), but the people of this specific country may interact ignorantly and stubbornly, and refuse to let me board the flight despite having the right to enter. They can ask me a Permanent Residency for example, and claim that my ID is not proof for them. How can I convince them that I effectively can? Note, I'm not asking HOW TO TRAVEL WITH 2 PASSPORTS, BUT in this way because of my particular circumstances.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/99439/discussion-on-question-by-abdul-what-to-do-if-gate-agents-refuse-to-accept-my-id).

Comment: Be well prepared - they don't have to recognize your ID as a valid one, but know if they support ePassports they can scan your ID card with the same machine and confirm that it's valid and issued by same authority issuing passports. The machine can't even tell any differences between an ID and a passport.